# Можно ли применять свойства display: flex для внуков, а не детей?

Tags: css, flexbox

Существует ли возможность применять стили от display: flex не для детей, а для внуков, как в примере:

```
<style>
    .block_flex {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .block_flex .item {
        align-self: center;
    }
</style>

<div class="block_flex">
    <a>
        <span class="item">Пункт</span>
    </a>
    <a>
        <span class="item">Пункт</span>
    </a>
    <a>
        <span class="item">Пункт</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

т.е. стили от .block_flex применились не к < a >, а к < span >?

Comment: нет, так нельзя

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению стили применяются только к дочерним элементам, по этому, на сколько я знаю, так нельзя.